# For $i\not = h \quad (1 \leq i, h \leq n), \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}A_{h,j} = 0$, where $A_{i,j}$ is the cofactor of $a_{i,j}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

> Let $A = (a_{i,j}) \in M_n (F),$ where F is a field.Prove that
>
> For $i\not = h \quad (1 \leq i, h \leq n), \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}
> > A_{h,j} = 0$, where $A_{i,j}$ is the cofactor of $a_{i,j}$.

I even don't have any intuition about how to prove this.I mean I have tried to start from the fact that if $i=h$, then it would give us the determinant of A, but it didn't go anywhere.After that I have consider to prove this by induction, but I couldn't derive the validity of the theorem from $n$ to $n+1$, so it was also a dead end, so I hoping you guy give some hints if you can, or a direct proof of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to understand this let  us simplify to considering an expansion in terms of the first row (there is no real loss of generality).

imagine for a matrix $M \in F_n$ that the first row is a variable vector $\bar x$ and the remaining $n-1$ rows $\bar r_2, \bar r_3, \dots, \bar r_n$ are fixed, defining the $n$ cofactors $A_j$.

the determinant of the matrix $M$ is then a function of $\bar x$, namely:
$$
D(\bar x) = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j A_j
$$
if $\bar x$ is equal to one of the rows $\bar r_2$ to $\bar r_n$ then $D$ is the determinant of a matrix with two rows equal, and hence zero.

Comment: I didn't get the last sentence of yours.

Comment: I mean, yes $\bar x$ is equal to one of the others, but I still don't get it how relate the fact that the determinant of a matrix with two rows equal is zero with this question.

Comment: try the simplest case, of 2x2 matrices, where the cofactors are just elements with adjusted sign.

Comment: Ok, got it.Thanks.